# TweetSharp send message to followers?

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anybody know if by using tweetsharp, one can send a message to a persons follow list?  I have made the following code that allows me to message a single person via userid, but not to a list.

Any ideas?

```
 var service = new 
       TweetSharp.TwitterService("ConsumerKey","ConsumerSecret","TokenKey","TokenSec
       retKey"); 
      var twitterStatus = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions() { Status ="Hello World" });
if (twitterStatus != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It worked");
}
```

Comment: You mean direct message?  What errors/wrong results do you get?

Comment: Are you wanting to send a list to all *your* followers? Or to someone else's?  I doubt twitter would let you spam other peoples followers.

Comment: Your probably going to have to obtain your follow list and iterate over it sending messages to each of them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by getting the TwitterService object to obtain followers, then follow up with the SendMessage function.

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService("key", "secret");
        service.AuthenticateWith(userToken, userSecret);

var friendship =
                service.GetFriendshipInfo(new GetFriendshipInfoOptions
                {
                    SourceScreenName = "handle",
                    TargetScreenName = "handle"
                });

if (friendship.Relationship.Source.FollowedBy)
            {
                yield return handle;
            }
```

Then on return do something like:

```
foreach (string handle in client.ReturnFollowingUsers(handles).Distinct()))
            {

                    TwitterDirectMessage dm = client.SendMessage(handle, message); 

            }
```